# Spark Streaming For Kafka:unable to read data from Kafka topic

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am trying out some hands-on on spark and I tried to use spark streaming to read data from a kafka topic and store that data in a elasticsearch index.
I am trying to run my code from my ide.
I added some messages in Kafka and ran my Kafka Streaming context program and it read the data but after that the program stopped.
So, if  I add new data in kafka , again I have to run my streaming context program.
I want the streaming context to keep 'listening' to the kafka broker , and I should not be running it each time I add some messages in Kafka broker.
Here is my code:

```
                  val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("KafkaStreams2")
                    val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(1))
                    val kafkaParams = Map(
                            "bootstrap.servers" -> "localhost:9092",
                            "key.deserializer" -> classOf[LongDeserializer],
                            "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
                            "group.id" -> "spark-streaming-notes2",
                            "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest"
                            )
                    // List of topics you want to listen for from Kafka
                    val topics = List("inputstream-sink")
                    val lines = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](ssc,
                            PreferConsistent,
                            ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams)
                            )

                    val word = lines.map(_.value())
                    word.print()
                    insertIntoIndexes()
                    ssc.start()
                    ssc.stop(stopSparkContext = false)
```

Comment: Why do you stop the context (last line) if you want to keep listening on new messages?

Comment: ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination() would wait till you kill the spark job.

Comment: @Knight71 thanks , solved the issue for me!